# Removing # from header

Tags: dataset, csv, matrix

I have a $(418,2)$ matrix and I want to convert it to **csv**. so I write:

```py
np.savetxt('titanic1.csv', Sol, fmt='%.2f', delimiter=",",header="PassengerId,Survived")
```

But the header I get is "# PassengerId" instead of "PassengerId" which is what I want. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) says you can add the parameter `comments=''`, but warns that np.loadtxt() might not work on the resulting file.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow morning. It's to upload the .csv file to kaggle. By the way I can't give you +1 because I don't have 15 reputation in this forum. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your header with the following code:

```py
for row in fileinput.input('titanic1.csv', inplace=True): 
    if fileinput.isfirstline(): 
        print('PassengerID,Survived') 
    else: 
        print(row)
```